# Does AppFabric Cache update the expiry time of cached items as they are retrieved?

Tags: .net, appfabric-cache

When an item is put into the cache it has a timeout assigned to it (either explicitly by the call to Put(), or implied from the cache config). I want to update/reset expiry on each item I retrieve [call Get() on].

Do I need to explicitly put/update the item or will the expiry time be automatically updated to Now + timeout?

**==UPDATE==**

Looks like the intention is that [ResetObjectTimeout() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424936.aspx) should be called. I see no other mention of expiry update logic in the docs.

**==UPDATE 2==**

In a quick test/experiment ResetObjectTimeout() generated as much network traffic as using Put(), so it's seems that the entire entry is being conveyed over the network just to update the timeout. I tried this with different amounts of data per item and the traffic level did indeed rise with amount of data despite the fact I'm not adding any new items.

The reason I want to update the timeout is that I want the cache items to remain in the cache for N minutes after they were last used. I expect this would be quite a common usage pattern, and to implement it I need to resend all of the data over the network per get operation, which greatly reduces the benefit of using the cache, e.g. limits scalability and performance.

Comment: did you tested ResetObjectTimeout with small objects ? Try to test with a big object of 5 MB. Because of WCF serialization, a simple message can take many Bytes. Your perf mab be degraded because of chatty AppFabric interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is all timeouts in appfabric are absolute.

As you found, there is a method in Data.Cache for reset timeout (in fact it allows you to apply a new timeout without getting data, not to rest in fact).

Depending on your scenario, Read-Through and Write-Behind could help take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377669.aspx)